# Thymeleaf not display value

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I tested Thymeleaf and I have a problem, because when I go to localhost and see my html view, dont see my "Test" value, which should be display on the website.
This is my code:

```
@Controller
public class DisplayData {
​
    @RequestMapping("/display")
    public String display(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("now", "Test");
        return "index.html";
    }
}
```

html view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
  <head>
    <meta charset=”utf-8″>
    <title>Hello World</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    Now is: <b th:text="${now}"></b>
  </body>
</html>
```

Path to index.html file is: resources/static/index.html

And localhost view:
[index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpNpu.jpg)

Comment: what happens if you return `"index"` instead of '"index.html"`. In thymeleaf you normally dont need the file suffix.(in default)

Comment: nothing display, only error from spring boot (Whitelablel error page). Path to my index.html is resources/static/index.html

Comment: why is your html in static folder? in default your html should be under templates

Comment: I dont know, but if i add index.html to templates folder, then again nothing display on localhost only spring boot error page

Comment: You should start from beginning. Using the defaults and you will have success.

Comment: I did everything just like in the example of Dhaval Simaria and it also does not work. Always displays Whitelabel Error Page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem.
I changed gradle dependencies: It was: 
*compile group: 'org.thymeleaf', name: 'thymeleaf', version: '3.0.7.RELEASE'*
Now is: *compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")*

Answer (score 1):

Three changes are required to make your application up-and-running:

1. `<meta charset=”utf-8″>` is not properly quoted. It should be `<meta charset="UTF-8"/>`
2. The default location of *index.html* file should be `resources/templates/index.html`
3. Your return statement should be `return "index";`, since you have annotated your class as *@Controller*, spring boot will understand that the string returned is the name of the view to be rendered. Then it will automatically check the above-mentioned location to find your view file.

You can refer [Spring Boot and Template Engines](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-template-engines).

Comment: @objectprogr If my answer was helpful in resolving your issue, please do mark it as 'Accepted.

Comment: No, after this change I have this error: This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Fri Sep 08 13:37:52 CEST 2017
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available

Comment: @objectprogr Hope you have not explicitly configured any other location for your view files other than the default. Because I have tried the exact scenario as yours in my machine and it is working.

Comment: I hope that not. This is my whole code on github https://github.com/objectprogr/fuelApp/tree/fuelV1/src/main. How to configured othr location for view?

Comment: @objectprogr Remove *@RestController* from *FuelApplication* class. That class is the starter class of your application and not a REST controller.

Comment: @objectprogr Remove the Thymeleaf 'Prefix' and 'Suffix' properties and give it a try. Also, check your RequestMapping: whether it is just */display* or */server2016/display*

Comment: @objectprogr Also, check your RequestMapping: whether it is just */display* or */{something}/display*

Comment: @objectprogr You check my code here on [GitHub](https://github.com/dhavalsimaria/General-Frameworkds/tree/master/SOThymeleaf)

Comment: I dont know why this not work. Maybe Intellij changed path to resources? This look like thymeleaf cant find my index.html. How to set path to templates folder in thymeleaf configuration? I must to write cobfiguration for View Resolvers?

Comment: @objectprogr You need not set path. Spring boot will do it for you. Refer the link that I have provided in the ***answer***.

Comment: Which link? To your github?

Comment: I check this link, but i still dont know what i must to do.

Comment: I made a new project and everything is the same as yours for github, but still does not work and only shows up Whitelabel Error Page

Comment: @ DhavalSimaria I update my question, because I solved a problem.

Comment: @objectprogr Bravo, finally U made it.

Comment: @ DhavalSimaria Thank you for your help!